# Uniform vs variable geometries

Tags: geometry, terminology

Euclidean, elliptic and hyperbolic geometry are all different. But they do share a common property: every part of space is "the same". There are no distinguished points that have different properties. All directions behave identically.

One could imagine a space that is finite along one axis, but infinite along another. And then different directions would have fundamentally different properties (regardless of the particular coordinate system that we use to measure them). One could imagine a space who's curvature isn't constant, but varies from point to point. And then different points would no longer be interchangeable.

(I don't know if anybody actually studies such things.)

What is the proper term for a geometry or a space which is "the same" all over? (And are Euclidean, elliptic and hyperbolic geometries the only ones possessing this property?)

Comment: You might be looking for this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space

Comment: @RandyE Yeah, I thought that might be the term. However, the Wikipedia article starts talking about "automorphism groups" and other such exotic terms. Also, it claims that the surface of a torus is considered homogeneous - while I would have thought that (for example) the inner edge of a torus is more sharply curved than the outer edge...

Comment: The definition in the article is more general than what you you're asking for, but what you're asking for is a special case of a homogeneous space.  In particular, what you are asking about is a homogeneous space where the automorphism group is the group of isometries of the space.  I don't know if there is a name for this special case offhand, and unfortunately, I also don't know what direction to point you in for a description with less exotic terms.

Comment: I take it the three geometries above are not the _only_ ones having this property then?

Comment: There are others.  For example, an infinite cylindrical tube has this property.  There is also a representation of the torus in 4 dimensions with this property.  But both of these can be constructed in terms of the spaces you gave using the Cartesian product.  I recall reading somewhere that all other spaces with this property can be constructed from the three you gave, but I don't recall where I read this.

Comment: Interesting. A cylinder has zero curvature everywhere, but doesn't appear to have the property of all directions being "the same"; if I travel around the radius, I quickly return to where I started, but if I travel along the other axis, I can travel forever without ever arriving back where I started...

Comment: Yep. This brings us to the topic of an istropic space.  This is a stronger condition than homogeneous space.  In an homegeneous space, every point is the same type of point, in some sense. In an isotropic space, from every point, things "look" the same in every direction (this means that an isotropic space is a homogeneous space).

Comment: Cool. Well, I've certainly learned some things tonight. If you could summarise this information as an answer, I think it essentially covers what I was asking about...